# Use the Static IP from my root Server to send Mails from my dynamic IP

Tags: networking, email, ip

Here i have the following scenario. I would like to maintain my own mail server due to data integrity and security risks. Also for easy backup etc. The problem is, that my ISP here in switzerland only provide dynamic IPs. E-Mails which are comming from SMTPs with a dynamic IP Adress will be rejected by nearly all big Mail providers. Therefore i had the following idea:

I have an root server somewhere else which has its own static public IP address. Now is there a way, i can use this IP Adress for all the traffic of my own server at home?

woudl this be possible with an IP2SEC Tunnel between those two servers?

Thank you for your answers :)

Regards
Claudio

Comment: Where does the term 'root server' come from, anyway? As opposed to just 'server', I mean.

Comment: @grawity Root server means dedicated server, as opposed to managed server or virtual (private) server. AFAIK it’s mostly used in Germany.

Comment: Im sorry, i meant a vServer with root access and not a managed server where i only have the possibility to upload some html files.

Answer (score 0):

A tunnel or VPN between the two can be useful but is not necessary – you can just use standard SMTP relay mechanisms.

- On the remote server, set up a TLS certificate and enable STARTTLS.
- Configure it to permit relaying for authenticated clients – you could use either regular username/password authentication, or TLS "client certificate" auth, depending on what the SMTP software supports. (In Postfix it'd be `permit_sasl_authenticated` or `permit_tls_clientcerts`.)
- Configure the *local* server to use your remote server as a "smarthost" or "relay host". There are plenty of Gmail-oriented tutorials, but they work just the same with any server.

Comment: Great! thank you for your answer. i will try it this way.